# Unable to set value dynamically for Lightning:InputField

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I have created a lightning component with lightning record edit form and a couple of fields. Wrote a Javascript method such that When I change the first field to a particular value then second field is updated. Below is my code.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
   <aura:attribute name='test' type='String'/>
   <lightning:recordEditForm 
                          aura:id="editForm"
                          objectApiName="Case"
                          recordTypeId="{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-p-around_x-small">
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="subject" fieldName="Subject" onchange="{!c.subjectChanged}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-p-around_x-small">
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="description" value="{!v.test}" fieldName="Description"/>
    </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

Below is the Controller code

```
({
    subjectChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        var subjectValue = component.find("subject").get("v.value");
        if(subjectValue === "U") {
            //var descriptionValue = component.find("description");
            //descriptionValue.set("v.value","User");
            component.set('v.test','User');
        }

    }
})
```

1. Updated Subject field to U, then Description got updated to 'User'
2. Update the Description field value to XYZ or clear the value.
3. Change the subject field to X and then update back to U.
4. Notice that JS method got executed, but description is not updated to 'User'.

Whenever, user updates subject field to U, I want the description to be set to User. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation

.....The assumption is that there are unsaved changes that **should not be overwritten**. If you want to be able to overwrite user changes, **you can use lightning:input instead**....

Comment: Thanks Bohdan Myrko. I fixed this using Lightning:input only and was more curious on why lightning:inputfield was not working. I think I overlooked or missed this part in  the documentation 'The assumption is that there are unsaved changes that should not be overwritten'.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around that.
You can bind your `inputField` value to an `aura:attribute`, and then set the value of the `aura:attribute`. This is particularly useful for Lookup fields on the object, where using `lightning:input` loses functionality.
Example:

```
<aura:attribute name="myFieldValue" type="string"/>
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="MyObject__c"
        onload="{!c.handleLoad}" 
        onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" 
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" 
        onerror="{!c.handleError}">
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="MyLookupField__c" value="{!v.myFieldValue}"/>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Javascript controller:

```
somethingHappened: function(newDataValue){
    component.set("v.myFieldValue", newDataValue);
}
```